# Can`t send array using ajax with asp.net core

Tags: jquery, asp.net, arrays, ajax, asp.net-core

I`ve wrote this ajax function:

```
$(function () {
        $("#showReport").click(function () {
            var data = [];
            for (var i = 0; i <@Model.LiFilters.Count;i++) {
                data[i] = $("#filter" + i).val();
                $("#myDiv").html("Hello!");
            }

            alert('{filters:' + JSON.stringify(data) + '}');
            $("#myDiv").remove();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("ShowReport", "Report")',
                traditional: true,
                //data: '{filters:' + JSON.stringify(data) + '}',
                data: { filters : data },
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    alert(data);
                    alert(response[0]);
                    $("#myDiv").html(response[0]);
                    alert(response);
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
```

And have this action in Report controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
public JsonResult ShowReport(string[] filters)
{
    C_AminReport aminReport = null;
    string sErr = string.Empty;
    //C_ReportParams aminParams = null;
    //C_AminReport aminReport;
    string sReport = "Empty Report!";
    if (C_AminReport.U_GetReport(aminReport.ID, out aminReport))
    {
        int iConIndex = Get_ServiceIndex();
        aminReport.U_RenderReport(iConIndex, ref sErr);
        aminReport.U_GetReportFromAmin(iConIndex, aminReport, out sReport, ref sErr);
    }
    string[] asReport;
    JsonBuilder.U_TryReadJson(sReport, out asReport);
    return Json(asReport);
}
```

But when run code i see data array filled but inside of the ShowReport action, fillters array is an empty array and not filled!
I also tries [FromBody] tag inside action params but it not works to!
What is the problem?

Comment: Open the developer tools of the browser and see how the request is being formatted. What does that JSON look like?

Comment: @GabrielLuci something looklike this: {filters:["1","2","3","4","5","6","7"]}

Comment: Try putting `[FromBody]` in front of `string[] filters`

Comment: @GabrielLuci when change it to "public JsonResult ShowReport([FromBody]string[] filters)", fillters set to null insted of string[0]!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tested your JavaScript and it's trying to send all the data in the query string.

You have to use `JSON.stringify`. One of these should work:

```
data: '{filters:' + JSON.stringify(data) + '}'
```

or

```
data: JSON.stringify(data)
```

I suspect it's the second that will work.

You may still need `[FromBody]`.

Answer (score 2):

you don't send an array, but an object with a property 'filters' that is an array.

```
{filters:["1","2","3","4","5","6","7"]}
```

As you pointed out in the comment :)

Try to send the array directly:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: '@Url.Action("ShowReport", "Report")',
   traditional: true,
   //data: '{filters:' + JSON.stringify(data) + '}',
   data: data, // <=== !!
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
```

Adding the attribute [FromBody] is also not a bad idea :-)

Comment: This line was not commented in my code! Somehow i tries your method and use data : data, and [FromBody] but it`s not works also :(

Comment: I meant the comment under your post ;-)
Anyway, do you get any response or any message from the failure or error handler?

Comment: There is no failure message just send something looks like this in Request Body: undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=

Comment: This is my request headers if you may need: Host: localhost:51519
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:58.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/58.0
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://localhost:51519/Report/ShowReport/13
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Content-Length: 76
Cookie: _ga=GA1.1.949841155.1515651415; .AspNetCore.Session=somecode
Connection: keep-alive

Comment: try 
data: JSON.stringify(data),

Answer (score 1):

I'm typing from mobile in the gym, so sorry for typos and poor syntax. I usually like to strongly type the input parameters of a controller. So instead of `string [] filters` you could have `FilterList filters` where `FilterList` is defined for example as

`public FilterList
 {
public List<string> filters {get; set;}
}`